# Multiple buttons calling a single method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to persist CSS user preference to my database according to which of six buttons is selected by the user.
On order to do this, I am trying to assign an integer value to each button click event; whichever is clicked will pass the corresponding integer as a parameter to my data access object to update the database able.

My method reads such:

```
    protected void SetCSS(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Users setCss = new Users();
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (sender.ToString() == "Blue")
            {
                setCss.StylePreference = 0;
            }
            else if (sender.ToString() == "Khaki")
            {
                setCss.StylePreference = 1;
            }
            else if (sender.ToString() == "Night")
            {
                setCss.StylePreference = 2;
            }
            else if (sender.ToString() == "Pink")
            {
                setCss.StylePreference = 3;
            }
            else if (sender.ToString() == "White")
            {
                setCss.StylePreference = 4;
            }
            else if (sender.ToString() == "Yellow")
            {
                setCss.StylePreference = 5;
            }

            setCss.UserLoginName = Session["eMail"].ToString(); // current user
            setCss.SetStylePreference(setCss.UserLoginName, setCss.StylePreference);
        }
```

In each button's click event:

```
    protected void btnBlue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetCSS(btnBlue, null);
    }

    protected void btnKhaki_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetCSS(btnKhaki, null);
    }
```

etc...

I put a watch on the sender object and, when the Pink button is selected, the value assigned to the sender reads
        {Text="Pink"}
However, as I step through the if statement in the SetCSS method, when I come to the 
        else if (sender.ToString() == "Pink")
the condition is not met and, rather than setting the style preference to 3 as it should, the program passes on to the end of the statement, finishing by always assigning a value of 0 to the property.

What am I doing wrong?
Would really appreciate help...

Comment: Since you're stepping through the code you should be able to see what the value of sender.ToString() is instead of "Pink" right?

Comment: I suspect that sender.ToString() is going to be "btnBlue", "btnPink", etc. As Andrew suggests, you should be able to see what the value is as you step through the code.

Comment: That's spot on; many thanks folks ;)

Comment: You are better off using swith/if statement with IDs. Type cast sender to button like Button btn = (Button)sender and switch using btn.ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `sender.Id.ToString()`

Calling `sender.ToString()` on an ASP.NET button will return "System.Web.Ui.Button" or something similar.

Paste the code related to how you setup the button and I'll clarify my answer more, as you could need either Id or Text depending on how you're setting the the name on your button.

Realistically, you can refactor this code to be a lot simpler.

You should map the `Click` event on all of your buttons to `SetCSS()`. Having a lot of scattered methods to only wrap the call is useless.

Comment: Hi Frazell, problem solved as per comments above; I altered if statement clauses to read: if(sender == btnBlue) etc.. Thanks for response..

Comment: @user1748443 Awesome. Glad you're issue is resolved. See my edited note about refactoring your code :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the if / else block to check for sender.Text

```
if (sender.Text.ToString() == "Blue")
        {
            setCss.StylePreference = 0;
        }
```

and do the same for the rest of the statements.